# How to summarize list FamousAuthors to another dictionary without using loop?

Tags: python

In the following list of famous authors tuples where each tuple has the following items:
(Author, Copies sold, Books are written, Nationality)

```
FamousAuthors =
 [(‘Agatha Christie’, 3000000, 85, ‘English’),
 (‘William Shakespeare’, 3000000, 42, ‘English’),
 (‘Barbara Cartland’, 750000, 723, ‘English’),
 (‘Danielle Steel’, 650000, 179, ‘American’),
 (‘Harold Robbins’, 750000, 23, ‘American’),
 (‘Georges Simenon’, 600000, 570, ‘Belgian’),
 (‘Enid Blyton’, 500000, 800, ‘English’),
 (‘Sidney Sheldon’, 485000, 21, ‘American’),
 (‘Gilbert Patten’, 312500, 209, ‘American’),
 (‘Dr. Seuss’, 300000, 44, ‘American’),
 (‘J. K. Rowling’, 280000, 15, ‘English’)]
```

Create a dictionary structure to summarize the data in FamousAuthors where each key is a
Nationality and the corresponding value is a tuple that contains
a. Number of authors,
b. Total copies sold,
c. Total books were written.
for that Nationality. Display the dictionary

I can only write this one using for loop. Could you please tell me some more visualized and easier ways?

Comment: Check out python docs on dictionaries. You'll probably need to familiarise yourself with the concept of `keys` and `values`. Your program should basically look something like this: 1. create and empty dictionary, 2. loop over the list! Inside the loop, you'll want to: 1. get the country, 2. check if the country is in the dictionary. If it is not, you'll need to set/initialise the tuple elements (a. Number of authors, b. Total copies sold, c. Total books were written.) to the values from the list, otherwise, if the country is in the dictionary, you'll need to add the values from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a problem like this, the answer is always pandas. It's very unpractical to work with dictionaries for your task as you will need to iterate over the items.

Convert your list into a `DataFrame` first

```
import pandas as pd

FamousAuthors = [
    ('Agatha Christie', 3000000, 85, 'English'),
    ('William Shakespeare', 3000000, 42, 'English'),
    ('Barbara Cartland', 750000, 723, 'English'),
    ('Danielle Steel', 650000, 179, 'American'),
    ('Harold Robbins', 750000, 23, 'American'),
    ('Georges Simenon', 600000, 570, 'Belgian'),
    ('Enid Blyton', 500000, 800, 'English'),
    ('Sidney Sheldon', 485000, 21, 'American'),
    ('Gilbert Patten', 312500, 209, 'American'),
    ('Dr. Seuss', 300000, 44, 'American'),
    ('J. K. Rowling', 280000, 15, 'English')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(FamousAuthors, columns=['author', 'copies',  'books', 'nationality'])
```

The beauty of pandas is that is very declarative as if you are talking to someone.

```
df.groupby('nationality').sum().T.to_dict('list')


{'American': [2497500, 476],
 'Belgian': [600000, 570],
 'English': [7530000, 1665]}
```

#### EDIT

Adding also the count of authors by nationality:

```
df.groupby('nationality').agg({'author': 'count', 'copies': 'sum', 'books': 'sum'}).T.to_dict('list')

{'American': [5, 2497500, 476],
 'Belgian': [1, 600000, 570],
 'English': [5, 7530000, 1665]}
```

As explained in the comments `.T` means the transpose.

Comment: could you please tell me what is the meaning of ' T.' in the df.groupby('nationality').sum().T.to_dict('list'). And if it is possible to add the number of authors by using panda?

Comment: ```.T``` just transposes the dataframe (rows and columns of the dataframe are swapped). Refer this for more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html